PHP CURL works with HTTPS on local machine but fails on hosted site, HTTP works on hosted site, fails on local machine
I ran into conflicting behaviors using CURL with HTTP vs HTTPS. The curl code runs an email logging routine in the background.
On my local machine this works, but fails on the hosted site:
$curl_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/email/_email_logging.php?log_id='.$log_id;

On the hosted site, this works, but fails on the local machine
$curl_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/email/_email_logging.php?log_id='.$log_id;

Complete CURL code:
$curl_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/email/_email_logging.php?log_id='.$log_id;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

An explanation of what could be happening would be appreciated and what tweak I could make to the CURL code to accept one of HTTP or HTTPS (preferred?) in both environments.

"fails" is not a good description of what happened. Curl reports error messages and codes which are the starting point for any problem analysis.

Adding this additional CURL line seems to have worked:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


Disabling host verification can have very serious security implications. Be careful.
